# Is there a function to replace value.labels with labels? R

Tags: r, label

I was opening a survey (from spss) in R.

I used this to open the survey:

```
b90 <- read.spss("empleo90.sav", use.value.labels = TRUE, to.data.frame = TRUE)
```

And I got all the variables labeled, how can I get a data frame that in column 1 tells you the variable name and in column 2 the label?

I tried this:

```
lab90 <- lapply(b90, attr, 'variable.labels')
lab90 <- data.frame(t(sapply(lab90,c)))
lab90 <- gather(lab90,key="variable", value="label")
```

But I only get "NULL" in the column 2.

The structure seems like this: (I don't know how to print it on the screen)

[image]

So how can I get the dataframe with the names and labels ?

Thanks in Advance!

---

Sorry here is the small reproducible example.

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(RN = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), ESTRATO = c(2, 
2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), CIUDAD = c("170150", "170150", "170150", 
"170150", "170150", "170150", "170150", "170150", "170150", "170150", 
"170150", "170150", "170150", "170150", "170150", "170150", "170150", 
"170150", "170150", "170150", "170150", "170150", "170150", "170150", 
"170150", "170150", "170150", "170150", "170150", "170150", "170150", 
"170150", "170150", "170150", "170150", "170150", "170150", "170150", 
"170150", "170150", "170150", "170150", "170150", "170150", "170150", 
"170150", "170150", "170150", "170150", "170150"), VIVIENDA = c("005", 
"009", "005", "007", "005", "011", "003", "005", "007", "008", 
"003", "010", "002", "001", "003", "004", "010", "001", "001", 
"001", "005", "005", "009", "002", "002", "003", "001", "008", 
"011", "001", "001", "009", "011", "010", "011", "003", "004", 
"001", "003", "004", "006", "007", "007", "009", "004", "004", 
"004", "009", "012", "010"), RELJEFE = structure(c(2L, 4L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 9L, 2L, 7L, 3L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Jefe", 
"Cónyuge", "Hijo o hija", "Yerno o nuera", "Padres suegros", 
"Nieto o nieta", "Otros parientes", "Empl. doméstica", "Otros no parient"
), class = "factor"), EDAD = structure(c(50L, 29L, 28L, 55L, 
41L, 25L, 37L, 40L, 61L, 38L, 23L, 36L, 20L, 41L, 56L, 21L, 22L, 
34L, 33L, 27L, 55L, 27L, 50L, 69L, 35L, 36L, 35L, 48L, 22L, 27L, 
26L, 56L, 32L, 38L, 30L, 22L, 34L, 29L, 49L, 44L, 42L, 61L, 31L, 
55L, 29L, 26L, 20L, 27L, 38L, 34L), .Label = c("Menos de un año", 
"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", 
"13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", 
"24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", 
"35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", 
"46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", 
"57", "58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", 
"68", "69", "70", "71", "72", "73", "74", "75", "76", "77", "78", 
"79", "80", "81", "82", "83", "84", "85", "86", "87", "88", "89", 
"90", "91", "92", "93", "94", "95", "96", "97", "98 y màs", "No informa"
), class = "factor"), SEXO = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Hombre", 
"Mujer"), class = "factor")), variable.labels = c(RN = "REGIÓN NATURAL", 
ESTRATO = "ESTRATO", CIUDAD = "CIUDAD", ZONA = "ZONA", SECTOR = "SECTOR", 
CONGLO = "CONGLOMERADO", AREA = "AREA", VIVIENDA = "VIVIENDA", 
HOGAR = "HOGAR", FORMUL = "FORMULARIO", PERSONA = "PERSONA", 
RESUMEN = "RESULTADO ENTREVISTA", NUMVIS = "NÚMERO DE VISITAS", 
NUMPERS = "NÚMERO DE PERSONAS", RELJEFE = "Relación de Parentesco", 
EDAD = "EDAD", SEXO = "SEXO", NIVINST = "Nivel de instrucción", 
ANOINST = "Año aprobado", ASISTEA = "Asiste a clases", SABELE = "Sabe leer y escribir", 
IESS = "Es afiliado al IESS", LININF = "N° Línea informante ", 
SIEMVIC = "Siempre vivio en ésta ciudad", CUANVIC = "Cuántos años vivio en ésta ciudad", 
DONVIAN = "Dónde vivio antes", TRABAJO = "Trabajó la semana pasada", 
ACTAYUDA = "Actividad que realizó para ayudar en su hogar", HORTRASA = "Horas de trabajo en la semana anterior", 
AUNOTRA = "Tiene trabajo del cual estuvo ausente", PORNOT = "Razón por la que no trabajó", 
HORTRAH = "Horas de trabajo habitual por semana", RATMEH = "Razón por la que trabajó menos de 40 horas", 
TRABN = "Cuántos trabajos tiene", BUSTRASA = "Buscó trabajo la semana anterior", 
BUSTRAMA = " Buscó trabajo el mes anterior", AMIGOS = "Amigos o parientes", 
DIRECTO = "Directo ante empleadores", PRENSA = "Prensa, radio", 
AGEPU = "Agencia pública de empleo", AGEPRI = "Agencia privada de empleo", 
TRESNE = "Establecer su propio negocio", TIEMBUS = "Tiempo que busca trabajo", 
MOTNOBUS = "Razón por la que no buscó trabajo", DESEATRA = "Desea trabajar actualmente", 
CONDINA = "Condición de inactividad", HORDIST = "Cuántas horas a la semana estaría disponible para trabaj", 
INGESPER = "Ingreso esperado por ese trabajo", TRABANT = "Trabajó anteriormente", 
TIEMNOT = "Número de meses que no trabaja", RAMA = "Rama de actividad", 
GRUPO = "Grupo de ocupación", CATETRAB = "Categoría de ocupación", 
PERTRABN = "Tamaño del establecimiento", NUPTRAB = "Número personas trabajan en el establecimiento", 
SALBASIC = "Salario básico", RULPAGO = "Cuánto recibio en el último pago ", 
FORMAPAG = "Forma de pago", COMIS = "Comisariato", VALCOM = "Valor de comisariato", 
PRES = "Prestamos", VALPRES = "Valor de prestamos", OTRASD = "Otras deducciones", 
VALOTD = "Valor de Otras deducciones", GEFEC = "Cuánto retiro de su negocio en efectivo", 
GMERC = "Cuánto retiro de su negocio en mercaderías", RENTAS = "Tuvo  ingresos por Rentas", 
VALREN = "Valor de ingreso por rentas", JUBIL = "Tuvo  ingresos por Jubilación", 
VALJUB = "Valor de ingreso por jubilación", OTROSI = "Otros ingresos", 
VALOTI = "Valor de otros ingresos", SEP = "Septiembre", OCT = "Octubre", 
NOV = "Noviembre", DIC = "Diciembre", ENE = "Enero", FEB = "Febreo", 
MAR = "Marzo", ABR = "Abril", MAY = "Mayo", JUN = "Junio", JUL = "Julio", 
AGO = "Agosto", FEXP = "Factor de expanción", CONDACT = "Condición de actividad", 
SECINS = "SECTOR INSTITUCIONAL", SUBEQU = "SUBEMPLEO EQUIVALENTE", 
INGRL = "INGRESO", PEAMSIU = "Sectorización de la PEA"), row.names = c(NA, 
50L), class = "data.frame")
```

---

The expected ouput should be a data frame that looks like this: the `var.labels`

```
name     label
RN       REGIÓN NATURAL
ESTRATO  ESTRATO
CIUDAD   CIUDAD
.          .
.          .
.          .
```

Comment: Can you provide a small reproducible example of data (with `dput`) and provide the expected output for it ?

Comment: You should also describe what search terms you have used in your exhaustive effort at find prior material on So and the web.

Comment: @RonakShah I just provided a small reproducible example within the actualization

Comment: Can you show what you want as expected output  for this data so that the target is clear ?